# Not able to get exact effective,final URL

Tags: go, httprequest, redirect

Using the Golang's http.Get() i am able to get effective or final url after multiple redirects,but in few cases where there are 303 redirects and special characters in URL golang is being weird, i am not able to get the actual final url. Following is the example i am dealing with - "http://swiggy.com//google.com/%2f.." , if we open this url in browser we get redirected to google, but i couldnt get the same using http.Get()

Comment: Show your code. Are you using Go 1.5 or later?

Comment: @CeriseLimón  am using go1.9 and the code is here - https://pastebin.com/2yAaqtqG

Comment: Code looks correct in you are using Go version with URL.RawPath functionality (needed for the %2f).  The application correctly follows the redirects from the server.  I suggest using browser dev tools and [CheckRedirect](https://godoc.org/net/http#Client.CheckRedirect) hook in client app to view redirects and see what's different.

Answer (score 2):

Other side behavior may depends on a lot of factors - for example of your User-Agent used, Cookies, IP and so on. Also sometimes it can change because of DDoS protection mechanism or things alike.

You may modify your app and see how it passes redirect stages:

Result:

```
getURL: http://swiggy.com//google.com/%2f..
Redirecting: 301 https://swiggy.com/google.com/%2f..
Redirecting: 301 https://www.swiggy.com/google.com/%2f..
Redirecting: 303 https://www.swiggy.com/google.com/%2f../
finalURL: https://www.swiggy.com/google.com/%2f../
Req Headers: map[Referer:[https://www.swiggy.com/google.com/%2f..]]
Resp Headers: map[Date:[Mon, 06 Nov 2017 12:51:20 GMT] Content-Type:[text/html; charset=utf-8] Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only:[default-src 'self';script-src https://chuknu.sokrati.com/15946/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://cdn.inspectlet.com/ https://tracking.sokrati.com/ https://connect.facebook.net/ https://bam.nr-data.net/ https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://js-agent.newrelic.com/ https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/static.swiggy/ https://*.juspay.in https://connect.facebook.net/ https://www.googletagmanager.com/ *.swiggy.in *.swiggy.com https://chat2.hotline.io/ 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-150997268072300';style-src https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://www.swiggy.com/ https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/static.swiggy/ https://chat2.hotline.io/ 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';img-src https://res.cloudinary.com/swiggy/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.google.co.in/ https://www.facebook.com/ https://tracking.sokrati.com/ http://api.swiggy.in/ https://api.swiggy.com https://d3oxf4lkkqx2kx.cloudfront.net/ https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://maps.gstatic.com/ https://csi.gstatic.com/ https://fonts.gstatic.com/ https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/ https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ https://www.google.com/ data: 'self'; font-src https://www.swiggy.com/ https://fonts.gstatic.com/ data: 'self';connect-src https://hn.inspectlet.com/ https://www.swiggy.com/ https://www.facebook.com/tr/ https://*.juspay.in/txns https://sentry.swiggyapp.com/ 'self';frame-src https://www.facebook.com/tr/ https://chat2.hotline.io/ https://*.webpush.hotline.io 'self';report-uri /csp/log] Etag:[W/"6f97-"] Vary:[Accept-Encoding] X-Data-Origin:[dweb_cluster/port-dweb-06 naxsi/waf rate-limiter-plain/rate-limiter-plain] X-Xss-Protection:[1; mode=block] Strict-Transport-Security:[max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload] X-Frame-Options:[Deny] Set-Cookie:[__SW=sjfsljfd; Path=/]]
```

Modified code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func CheckRedirect(r *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
    fmt.Println("Redirecting:", r.Response.StatusCode, r.URL)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    getURL := "http://swiggy.com//google.com/%2f.."
    fmt.Println("getURL:", getURL)
    client := &http.Client{
        CheckRedirect: CheckRedirect,
    }
    resp, err := client.Get(getURL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    finalURL := resp.Request.URL.String()
    fmt.Println("finalURL:", finalURL)
    fmt.Println("Req Headers:", resp.Request.Header)
    fmt.Println("Resp Headers:", resp.Header)
}
```